# What is the best way to make a common task closure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

Don't panic due to huge code snippet, you just need to understand that in my code I've multiple functions with same repetitive code. I want to make a common task closure, but every task closure at least has few (here 2) lines which are specific for every task closure.

I've  Corona background in which I used to keep a common file ( You can think it as a class ) for all server related code (simply all HTTP calls). Which were best there so multiple common things could be generalized for multiple functions to use.

If I make a common task closure then how would I pass this data to a specific VC (whose name is passed to specific functions as a parameter)

Please let me understand how iOS developers implement it. What are the few best practices?
You can just see 1-2 functions don't need to understand my entire code.

Please don't suggest Alamofire, I don't want to rely on 3rd party Libraries.

```
 import Foundation



class Server
{
    static let baseURL="http://www.bewrapd.com/api/call/"

    class func convertDataToArray(_ data: Data) -> NSArray
    {

        do
        {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data , options: [])

            print(json)

            return json as! [[String:AnyObject]] as NSArray

        }


        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }

        return []
    }

    class func convertStringToDictionary(_ data: Data) -> [String:AnyObject]?
    {

        do
        {

            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

            return json
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }

        return nil
    }

    //-----------------------------------------

    class func tryToLogin(target: LoginViewController, userName: String, password: String )
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"checkLoginForIos")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userName="+userName+"&password="+password
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData!)

        }

        task.resume()

    }

    class func fetchCarsForUser(target: CarSelectionViewController)
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"getAddedCarsByUser")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userId=\(userId!)"
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

            let finalData = Server.convertDataToArray(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData as! [[String : AnyObject]])


        }
        task.resume()


    }

    class func updateCarsStatusForUser(target: CarSelectionViewController, carId: Int, status: Bool)
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"updateCarBookingStatus")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "carId=\(carId)&status=\(status)"
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")


            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            target.carStatusChangeCallback(finalData!)


        }

        task.resume()

    }


    class func unbookCar(target: MenuController, status: Bool)
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"updateCarBookingStatus")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "carId=\(carId!)&status=\(status)"
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")


            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData!)


        }

        task.resume()

    }

    //-----------------------------------------

    class func fetchCurrentCampaign(target: CampaignViewController )
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"getCurrentCampaign")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userId=\(userId!)&carId=\(carId!)"
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        //--------------

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData!)

        }

        task.resume()


    }

    class func fetchCarHistory(target: HistoryTableViewController )
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"campaignHistory")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userId=\(userId!)&carId=\(carId!)"
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            let finalData = Server.convertDataToArray(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData as! [[String : AnyObject]] as NSArray)


        }
        task.resume()
    }

    class func fetchTripsForCampaign(target: TripsViewController, jobId: Int )
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"gpsHistory")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "jobAppId=\(jobId)"
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            let finalData = Server.convertDataToArray(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData as! [[String : AnyObject]] as NSArray)


        }
        task.resume()
    }

    class func fetchTripsGeoCoordinates(target: RoutesMapViewController, tripId: Int )
    {

        //------
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"mapHistory")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "tripId=\(tripId)"
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            let finalData = Server.convertDataToArray(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData as! [[String : AnyObject]] as NSArray)


        }
        task.resume()
    }

    class func fetchCampaignList(target: CampaignListViewController )
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"getCampaignList")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userId=\(userId!)&carId=\(carId!)"//+String(describing: userId)
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200
            {
                // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            let finalData = Server.convertDataToArray(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData as! [[String : AnyObject]] as NSArray)


        }
        task.resume()
    }

    class func applyForCampaign(target: JoApplyViewController, campaignId: Int )
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"applyCampaign")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "campaignId=\(campaignId)&userId=\(userId!)&carId=\(carId!)"

        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")


            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData!)

        }

        task.resume()


    }

    class func sendTripData(target: MapViewController, tripDataJSONStr: String)
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"sendTripCordinatesForIos")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "request=" + tripDataJSONStr

        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")


            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            target.nextAction(finalData!)

        }

        task.resume()


    }


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `closer`?

Comment: Please review now it's "closure"

Comment: Am sorry it's closure.

Comment: One best practice aside from the question is **not** to use `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift. The syntax `as! [[String:AnyObject]] as NSArray` is pretty silly and defeats the strong type system. Consider also that a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` in Swift 3.

Comment: Alamofire is a well reputed and maintaind library and a  lot of apps out there are using it. So why not ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal bcz apple can restrict anything(3rd party), it has it's own learning curve. And again how I could compress my code even though I use Alamofire, I've multiple "Task Closure".

Comment: I've used class function so that it can be called without creating objects, is it correct or I should use instance method. And Singleton object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use closure as following, not sure if you need any other requirement, there are actually no difference with your current code, just easier to work with:

```
class func tryToLogin(userName: String, password: String, completion: (_ result: [String:Any])->() )
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseURL+"checkLoginForIos")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userName="+userName+"&password="+password
        print("### \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

            let finalData = Server.convertStringToDictionary(data)
            completion(finalData)

        }

        task.resume()

    }
```

On your `LoginViewController`, just call it normally, name the data dict and call `nextAction(finalData!)` on closure

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single method which will look like this:

```
 class func makeWebServiceCall(url:URL,postString:String,completionClosure:@escaping(_ success:Bool, _ data:Data?, _ response:HTTPURLResponse?, _ error:Error?)->Void){

            var request =  URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

            let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let respData = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    completionClosure(false,data,response as? HTTPURLResponse,error)
                    return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200
                {
                    // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                    completionClosure(false,data,response as? HTTPURLResponse,error)
                    return
                }
                let responseString = String(data: respData, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
                completionClosure(true,data,response as? HTTPURLResponse,error)

            }

            task.resume()
        }
```

Now call this method from any view controller and handle the response in designated view controller separately.

```
Server.makeWebServiceCall(url: URL(string:"")!, postString: "", completionClosure: { (isSuccess, data, response, error) in
                if isSuccess{
                print("call is success")
                }else{
                print("ohh no, call failed")
                }
            })
```